# Does protege support Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I am working on a Final year project which is Domain Specific Search Engine using Web Semantics and [Ontology](https://www.w3.org/OWL/). After doing some research, I found [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/), which is a tool for creating ontology class and implementing [SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) queries.

I have decided to use Node.js as my back-end language for this project and have looked upon how to connect protege with Node.js but haven't come up with any successful result.

Kindly let me know whether it supports Node.js or not and what other languages it does support. If it does support, how do we connect it with Protege?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Khan,

Protege is a tool for ontology engineering. Once you begin thinking about a real back-end based on Node or any other framework, you should import the ontology you have made (in the majority of cases, just a TBox) into a triplestore, add some data (ABox) that does not have any logical inconsistencies with the TBox and then make SPARQL queries from your backend.

Thus, your question can be reduced to two simpler ones:

1. How to import your ontology developed in Protege into a triplestore and configure reasoning (pick Fuseki, RDF4j, Virtuoso, Stardog or any other triplestore and then search for docs on the reasoner support for each triplestore).
2. How to make SPARQL queries from Node-based backend to the triplestore. Just search npm for 'SPARQL'.